# How do round a number say 83.3 double to 84 integer

Tags: asp.net

How do round a number say 83.3 double to 84 integer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use in c#: Math.Ceiling()

and then just convert it into an int32

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) method

> Returns the smallest integral value
>   that is greater than or equal to the
>   specified double-precision
>   floating-point number.

and then convert to integer using

[Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(VS.71).aspx) Method

Answer (score 1):

**Ceiling** function returns smallest integer greater than floating number:

```
double number = Math.Ceiling(83.3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an int you can do:

```
double d = 83.3;
int i = (int)Math.Ceiling(d);
```